# Content not appearing when I add script on head, why?

Tags: html

Hello when I remove the text in head

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" src="index.CSS">
<script SRC="index.is">
```

The form appear but when I enter the text the form dissapear
Even tho the CSS and js files are all empty I haven't writer anything
Code
:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Organic Pe sign up</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" src="index.css">  
  <script src="index.js">
</head>
<body>
      <section>
          <div class="bix">
             <div class="form">
                 <h2>Sign Up</h2>
                 <form>
                   <div class="uc">
                     <input type="text" placeholder="Username"></input>
                     <img src="user.png"></img>
                   </div>
                   <div class="uc">
                     <input type="text" placeholder="Password"></input>
                      <img src="lock.png"></img>
                   </div>
                   <label class="remember"><input type="Checkbox">Remember Me</input></label>
                 </form>
             </div>  
          </div>
      </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ironically, while you failed to include the mandatory end tag for `<script>` you have included end tags for `<input>` and `<img>` where they are forbidden. Use a validator to error check your HTML: https://validator.nu/

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close the `<script>` tag. Replace the following:

```
<script src="index.js">
```

With this:

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
```